# Can I stop taking pictures of my dog?

Tags: nintendogs-and-cats

I am getting really tired of accidentally bumping <kbd>R</kbd> and taking a picture of my dog. My dog is cute and all, don't get me wrong, but there are only so many pictures of a cute puppy that a person needs.

Is there any way to disable the camera buttons? Or am I stuck with a plethora of puppy pictures everywhere I turn?

Comment: Hold your DS differently? :P

Comment: Open the DS and slip a piece of paper in between the R-button and it's contact?

Comment: @Gwen you sound like you work for Apple

Comment: -1 "there are only so many pictures of a cute puppy that a person needs." blatant lying.

Comment: @Ronan I prefer cute pictures of cats...

Comment: @Alex if only! But the 3DS does just enter camera mode in the main menu on the shoulder buttons so I have taken to holding it differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the SD card from the 3DS while playing. Since that is where the pictures are saved, it will prevent them from being taken.

Comment: -1 Speculation.

Comment: It actually does work - a message pops up saying "No SD card inserted" if I try to take pictures without it in. It's still a little irritating, but a lot less so than the camera flash, and this way I don't randomly fill more SD card space than I want to.

Comment: @Ashley Nunn Glad that it helped out, regardless of whether some think I was speculating :p

Comment: @danRhul "Try" and "Maybe" weren't in my original answer, not sure why mod edits tone of answer and I take the hit, but yes, glad you at least explained downvote, most don't

Comment: @curtisk Just seen that, I'll take it off, and was the accepted answer so +1

Comment: Hi curtisk. In the original form your answer was flagged by other users as "not an answer" because it looked like you're answering a question with a different question of your own. I've edited your answer to clarify you're suggesting a solution, not asking something unrelated. If you have any problems with my specific wording you're welcome to change it yet again!